# Equivalent from PHP hash_hmac("sha384", $data, $key) in .NET

Tags: c#, php, .net

In PHP i do following steps:

```
<?php
  $key="mM8Y28b5R7KFe3Y5";   
  $data="298052380sbEUREinzellizenz Spieler SEN329739test120211572380R-00001003authorization19";
  $hash=hash_hmac("sha384", $data, $key);
  echo $hash;
?>
```

i get following output:

```
f34fb28f6462cde18a92ee854d289ba5aed3cfc07d0abb52cfef3b70028e1b38b098ae17514a9121d43d3d6f684eccd8
```

I try to do this in .NET with:

```
string data = "298052380sbEUREinzellizenz Spieler SEN329739test120211572380R-00001003authorization19";
      string key = "mM8Y28b5R7KFe3Y5";
      string hash = "";
      using (SHA384 sha384Hash = SHA384.Create())
      {
        byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] hashBytes = sha384Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
      }
```

and i get

```
77b7eccd4f66b07c66e2c49b83e53bf84dfd4dc67ec60007df4476adfe16d9b0bfdd6e58e9a5008bde4908335d161ef5
```

i tried also:

```
var keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
      using (HMACSHA256 sha384Hash = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
      {
        byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] hashBytes = sha384Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        hash2 = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
      }
```

hash2 is

```
ceaabe254e19d77940ac3edfdf2fa3d1de424d569136e8deb770aa81be5cb24a
```

i don't get the difference. I checked already the Encodings, but i see no differents.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the second example but with

```
using (HMACSHA384 sha384Hash = new HMACSHA384(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)))
```